# Two column data binding in a listbox trouble

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

My understanding of DataBinding is still at the "working on it" level, so here is my issue. I have this data:

```
private class User
    {
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string real_name { get; set; }
    }

ObservableCollection<User> users = new ObservableCollection<User>();
...adds stuff...
CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(users);
```

I want this to be displayed in a two column ListBox. I've gotten in in a two column ComboBox by doing:

```
<ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="114,23,0,0" Name="comboBox_client" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="113" IsEditable="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding username}" Name="left" Width="50" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding real_name}" Name="right" Width="100" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

with

```
comboBox_client.ItemsSource = view;
```

But I'm not sure how to make the step over to a ListBox, since I see no ItemTemplate, and I don't understand the concept behind what the above Xaml is actually doing. If I take out the ItemTemplate part and try the rest on the ListBox, I just just a listbox full of System.Windows.DataTemplate.

Point in the right direction please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ListBox has an `ItemTemplate` property too. I think you just missed that.

You can just use the same `DataTemplate` you used for your `ComboBox`.

Comment: Hah, thanks! I don't really know how I missed that. Actually, I do know how, I didn't scroll down more on the Intellisense. This is what I get for 4:30 AM programming

Comment: @cost No problem at all, glad I helped. But I think what you really need is some sleep :)

Answer (score 1):

ListBox:

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding username}" Width="50" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding real_name}" Width="100" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

But it seems to me, ListView is more suitable for this task:

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="User name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding username}" Width="50" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding RealName}" Width="100" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: Yea I some how missed that ListBox had an ItemTemplate. I didn't really want anything other than listing them, so I saw no initial need to use ListView. Though Perhaps I should add a nice header for my columns. I just need to look up how to do that, I've never actually worked with a listview before